# What does :: mean after declaring an object?

Tags: c++

I am trying to do some hello world stuff after completing [the standard c++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). The first thing I tried doing is drawing directly on the screen without a window. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981621/how-to-draw-to-screen-in-c) and it works.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HDC screenDC = ::GetDC(0);
    ::Rectangle(screenDC, 200, 200, 300, 300);

    int exit; cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

But nowhere in the standard c++ tutorial does it cover anything like this

```
HDC screenDC = ::GetDC(0);
::Rectangle(screenDC, 800, 200, 300, 300);
```

What is Rectangle a member of?

---

If you don't mind I have some other questions that might be simple. If not don't worry about it.

- As soon as my rectangle has a window move over it, it disappears. Is there a callback to let me know about this so I can repaint?
- How do I change the color of my rectangle?
- Where can I go to learn about this? Every tutorial I have found has been sparse and most have been out of date. I can get a book if that's what I need to do. Have tried the following (sometimes with success and sometimes not):
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384843.aspx
- http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533895(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: By the way, that C++ tutorial is in no way "standard".

Comment: That is the *scope resolution operator*. In this case, `::Rectangle` means that the function `Rectangle` lives in the global namespace

Comment: It's a much better idea to have a topmost, fullscreen, colour key window instead of drawing on the screen. Use `CreateSolidBrush` and select it into the DC or something to change colour (there's a lot of info on GDI on MSDN), and Petzold's book is wonderful.

Comment: Please don't add additional questions not relevant to the original question - create new questions for these items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::` like that accesses the global namespace. It is namespace resolution. You can just drop those `::` if you like, they are extra cruff.

Comment: You can drop them here; but sometimes you need them to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: Well, you can drop them in *this case*. But if you're currently in a different namespace, which also has something with the same name, just writing the symbol name will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 9):

`::` is the scope resolution operator.

`scope::name` means use the name declared in the class or namespace called `scope`.

`::name` means use the name declared in the global namespace. Usually, it's optional; but sometimes you need it if there's something else with the same name in the current scope.

Comment: Specifically, `::` is the [scope resolution operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm).

Comment: @Caleb: Yeah, I guess I should mention that. I assumed the OP knew what it was (since he asked "What is Rectangle a member of?"), but completeness is good.

Answer (score 2):

`::` is the scope resolution operator. `::Identifier` will refer to anything in the global namespace. It is not always necessary however. It's only really needed when **not** using it will cause an ambiguity:

```
int i = 0;

void func() {
    int i = 0;

    ::i = 1; // This will set the global i
    i = 1; // This will set the local i
}
```

(Note: I do not endorse globals in any way)

Answer (score 1):

:: is used to access things that are in classes or namespaces. (Or in this case, that are not.)

So if you have a class Foo with a static method bar you can call it like this
`Foo::Bar();`

Also, if you have a namespace MyLibrary with a function PrintPrettyThings you can call it like this:
`MyLibrary::PrintPrettyThings();`

And if you have another function Bar somewhere and you are inside a method of Foo you can use
`::Bar();` to call the Bar that is outside of Foo, otherwise you will just call Foo::Bar.